# Copy Pointers of Object into New Pointer of this Object

Tags: c++

I have a class, GameObject, which has a `std::vector<Component*> mComponents` and I have overloaded the `GameObject(const GameObject&)`. I am trying to copy the mComponents over from one to the other, but making each of the contained `Component*`'s into a `new` object entirely, but keeping the objects contents exactly the same. This is what I have at the moment:

**GameObject.cpp**

```
GameObject::GameObject(const GameObject& other) 
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        this->mComponents = other.mComponents; // EDIT 1
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)mComponents.size(); i++)
        {
            // FILL this->mComponents with NEW objects but
            // containing the exact same data and 
            // variables from other.mComponents
            this->mComponents[i] = other.Copy(); // EDIT 2 EXAMPLE OF IDEA IN COMMENTS
            this->mComponents[i]->setParent(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Engine.cpp (Extract)**

```
GameObject cube, cube2;

cube.addComponent(new DirectionalLight(glm::vec3(-0.2f, -1.0f, -0.3f)));
cube.addComponent(new Texture("Resources/Textures/container.png", "Resources/Textures/container_specular.png"));
cube.addComponent(new Shader("Resources/Shaders/cube.shader"));
cube.addComponent(new Cube());

cube2 = GameObject(cube);
```

When I instantiate cube2, the mComponents `Components*` contents all stay exactly the same but I would like to create a new `Component*`'s to fill this `std::vector` from the `GameObject(const GameObject&)` fucntion, whilst keeping all the variables the same.

*P.s. I know that most other operators such as '=' will not create new Components for inside the vector but I will be implementing that aswell after I figure out how to fill the vector with new `Component*`'s.*

Comment: `this->mComponents[i] = new Component(*other.mComponents[i])`? I'm not sure what's unclear.

Comment: that did the trick, didn't properly know how to lay out the syntax for what I needed, thanks!

Comment: In a copy constructor, `this` will NEVER be equal to `&other`.

Comment: @Peter just doing it incase I parse the same object to itself through the copy constructor accidentally

Comment: @melpomene *if* this works *then* keeping pointers in the vector probably doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Sharpie - it is not possible to pass an object to itself via the copy constructor.   An object doesn't exist before the copy constructor completes initialising it.  Passing a reference to the copy constructor means the object must already exist before the copy constructor is invoked

Comment: @Peter sorry dad.. I understand now ahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this->mComponents[i]->Copy(other);` Will not work. At least, not from a pure inheritance standpoint. A supertype (base) type pointer cannot be implicitly cast to a derived type. This is called downcasting, and no language supports it implicitly.

A simpler way to do it is to define a virtual "clone" function in each component:

```
virtual Component* clone()=0; // base declaration

virtual Component* Texture::clone() //derived implementation
{
    return new Texture(*this);
}
```

Then in your game object copy constructor:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)other.mComponents.size(); i++)
    {
        // FILL this->mComponents with NEW objects but
        // containing the exact same data and 
        // variables from other.mComponents
        this->mComponents.push_back(other.mComponents->clone());
        this->mComponents[i]->setParent(this);
    }
```

This way, you let the component itself handle the copying process.

Comment: yeah that was what I was trying to suggest, but messed up my syntax by alot cause I was rushing to go to gym, thanks @Ian Young